# Move-Item Path as a variable

Tags: powershell

Part of my script looks as follows:

```
move-item -path $_.FullName+"\*.7z" -destination "$destination"
```

it returns error:

> Move-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts
>   argument '+*.7z'. At line:32 char:4
>   +             move-item -path $_.FullName+"*.7z" -destination "$destin ...
>   +             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Move-Item], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand

But, if I change that variable to exact value, that works:

```
move-item -path "D:\test1\test2\test3\test4\*.7z" -destination "$destination"
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use *expressions* as part of a command line - which is parsed in *argument mode* - you must *force a new parsing context* with `(...)`:

```
Move-Item -path ($_.FullName+"\*.7z") -destination "$destination"
```

See [`Get-Help about_Parsing`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing).

---

In this instance, given that the expression is constructing a *string* value, using an *expandable (interpolating) string* with an embedded subexpression (`$(...)`) is a viable alternative, as shown in [Ben Richard's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44146957/45375).

Answer (score 0):

To do what you want you can use an expression inside a string, without doing the string concatenation.

```
# $_.FullName is an expression
# so to have used inside the quotes, you need to wrap it with $()
Move-Item "$($_.FullName)\*.7z" $destination
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.